# Visual Studio 2017 locking files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio Version 15.2 (26430.6) Release.

Having recently updated to the above version I am running into continuous issues with VS locking up files when trying to build.

Could not copy "obj\Debug\projHype.dll" to "bin\Debug\projHype.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

Also tried running VS2017 with and with out admin priveledges

I tried the suggestions for older versions of visual studio but to no avail.  Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: This means that a process that uses the file is still running. It could be a build step that hang, or a test runner that didn't terminate correctly. You can use Process Explorer to find which process uses this file handle. I've encountered this problem with various VS versions and test runners in the past.

Comment: This problem can also appear if you debug a web site under IIS and terminate debugging abruptly. The dll is still loaded in the site's application pool (app domain actually) and won't be released until you recycle the apppool or IIS

Comment: What kind of project are you building? Do you use Resharper, Unit test runners, build tools, analyzers, or anything else that may be using your dlls? An external application or test project that is still running perhaps?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Using Process Explorer, it is DevEnv.exe that is locking the file, not one of it's child processes. It will build fine several times, then start failing.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. The VS process is locking the file and the only way I can get around is to restart VS so I can manually delete. Very annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone encountering this. Updating to version 26430.12 will resolve this. Looks like the previous release contained a bug.

Comment: Running into the same issue, but it is specific to the bin/Roslyn folder. I am running VS2017  version 26430.13

Comment: Still seeing this behavior in VisualStudio 2019 Preview as of today so maybe an update doesn't fix it after all.

Answer (score 1):

While there may be other causes, testhost.exe and testhost.x86.exe can both result in a lock that prevents the build from completing. The symptoms are bewildering-- the test explorer churns indefinitely, sometimes timeout warnings appear in the build. Sometimes the files cannot be accessed even after VS is shut down.

If you are using nUnit or another test framework, make sure that test discovery does not encounter any infinite loops or crashes in your code. If this happens, it can hang the testhost executable. For example, if you use nUnit TestCase or TestCaseSource, if any of these perform an action that can hang, lock up, or crash, they will be invoked *before* the tests are executed.

This is the tricky bit-- your tests haven't run yet, but your code can lock up VS! While this may not be your problem, if you have unit test discovery in any way, check that it all completes.

One way to make sure all discovery completes is to use the functions from a test itself, and disable them as a TestCase or TestCaseSource (or equivalent in other test frameworks). If the test hangs or crashes, that's the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to run the program again with accepting "run last successful build". After the run, the locks were gone.